# R sequential labelling of subgroups dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing 4000 unique ID and around 350k rows.

I am struggling to find a solution to solve the following problem:
For each single ID, create a sequantial ID to label each subgroup (**that restart from 1 for each new ID**) that would allow me to collapse the dataframe by keeping only the head and tail of each subgroup for each single ID.

This would allow me to continue in my project  by dealing some operation on the other features of each head and tail element for each subgroup in each ID.

Here is the code to replicate the example:

```
ID <- rep(1, 11)
Time <- seq(1:11)  
Type <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5)  
df1 <- data.frame(ID, Time, Type)  

ID <- rep(2, 9)
Time <- seq(1:9)
Type <- c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)
df2 <- data.frame(ID, Time, Type)

ID <- rep(3, 5) 
Time <- seq(1:5) 
Type <- rep(4, 5)  
df3 <- data.frame(ID, Time, Type)  

ID <- rep(4, 10)  
Time <- seq(1:10)
Type <- c(5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)  
df4 <- data.frame(ID, Time, Type)  

df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4)  

label <-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)  
label_df<- cbind(df, label)
```

The final solution should look like this and needs to be applied to 4000 unique ID for a total of around 350k rows:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4)  
Type <- c(4,4,3,3,5,5,2,2,3,3,2,2,4,4,5,5,2,2,1,1)  
Time <- c(1,4,5,8,9,11,1,3,4,6,7,9,1,5,1,3,4,6,7,10)      
Label <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,3,3)  
solution_df <- data.frame(ID, Type, Time, Label)
```

NB: the label I am looking for is a sequential number that increase each one the Type changes. This means that for example, the outcome for ID == 2 must be

```
ID2 <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2)
Time_ID2 <- c(1,3,4,6,7,9) 
Type_ID2 <- c(2,2,3,3,2,2)
Label_ID2 <-c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
```

and NOT

```
Label_ID2 <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1)
```

I hope the question is clear and I followed the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has requested to number each streak of contiguous rows with identical values of `Type` within each `ID` group.

This requires to use the `rleid()` function to create labels:

```
library(data.table)
result <- setDT(df)[
  # create labels for grouping
  , Label := rleid(Type), by = ID][
    # pick first and last element of each group
    , .SD[c(1L, .N)], by = .(ID, Label)]

all.equal(setcolorder(result, names(solution_df)), setDT(solution_df))
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

```
result
```

> ```
>     ID Type Time Label
>  1:  1    4    1     1
>  2:  1    4    4     1
>  3:  1    3    5     2
>  4:  1    3    8     2
>  5:  1    5    9     3
>  6:  1    5   11     3
>  7:  2    2    1     1
>  8:  2    2    3     1
>  9:  2    3    4     2
> 10:  2    3    6     2
> 11:  2    2    7     3
> 12:  2    2    9     3
> 13:  3    4    1     1
> 14:  3    4    5     1
> 15:  4    5    1     1
> 16:  4    5    3     1
> 17:  4    2    4     2
> 18:  4    2    6     2
> 19:  4    1    7     3
> 20:  4    1   10     3
> ```

Comment: BEST SOLUTION! Extremely easily applied to the all dataset of 400k rows. Worked perfectly and run pretty fast.
Then, I converted the solution back to data frame because I don't know to properly deal with data tables yet. PERFECT!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(label = as.integer(factor(Type, levels = unique(Type)))) %>%
```

basically after grouping by ID, convert Type to factor and back to integer within each group.

However this approach counts each unique value of Type to belong to the same subgroup. For instance: `5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5` is labeled `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1`. If your intention is `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3` it is better to use `rle` function:

```
       df %>%
         group_by(ID) %>%
         mutate(label = rep(1:length(rle(Type)$lengths), times = rle(Type)$lengths))
#part of output:
12  2    2     1
13  2    2     1
14  2    2     1
15  2    3     2
16  2    3     2
17  2    3     2
18  2    2     3
19  2    2     3
20  2    2     3
```

Comment: Thank you but as you said my intention is to treat each subgroup differently therefore I need a sequential label that basically indexes all the groups.

Comment: Thank you, you completed the most critical task however the final outcome is missing

Comment: As I said, your solution is great but that of @Uwe is perfect! Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: @Enrico If the solution by Uwe suits your needs best you should mark it as accepted for future generations. This is how SO operates.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tidyverse`:

If the ordering is to be preserved and each first and last observation per **ID+Type block** is to be preserved, independent wether the ID+Type-Groups are repeated, the following is possible using `lag()` and `lead()`, which simply checks wether there is a change in the number for one of the two identifying variables.

```
df %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number(),
           nr = nrow(.),
           select1 = ifelse(Type!=lag(Type), 1, 0) + 
               ifelse(Type!=lead(Type), 1, 0) + 
               ifelse(ID!=lag(ID), 1, 0) + 
               ifelse(ID!=lead(ID), 1, 0),
           select2 = ifelse(id==1, 1, 0) + ifelse(id==nr, 1, 0)) %>% 
    filter(select1>=1 | select2>=1) %>% 
    select(-id, -nr, -select1, -select2)
```

For the labels, the solution by [missuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47200233/7161188) with `rle()` seems the most stringent solution, therefore, you could get everything done in one step if you add that part before, or get everything into one step:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Label = rep(1:length(rle(Type)$lengths), times = rle(Type)$lengths)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number(),
           nr = nrow(.),
           select1 = ifelse(Type!=lag(Type), 1, 0) + 
               ifelse(Type!=lead(Type), 1, 0) + 
               ifelse(ID!=lag(ID), 1, 0) + 
               ifelse(ID!=lead(ID), 1, 0),
           select2 = ifelse(id==1, 1, 0) + ifelse(id==nr, 1, 0)) %>% 
    filter(select1>=1 | select2>=1) %>% 
    select(-id, -nr, -select1, -select2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply but in this case, I lose the possibility of taking head and tail of each subgroup since subgroups that appear in different orders but having same Type got merged.

I updated the question to be more clear:     ID2 <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2 
    Type_ID2 <- c(2,2,3,3,2,2)
    Label_ID2 <-c(1,1,2,2,3,3)

Comment: Furthermore the ID does not reset from 1 each time there is a new ID.

Comment: This questions the setup a little bit. What if the data frame is arranged differently? Then the results would be completely different, as the groups of observations per ID and Type are not enough to identify the observations you actually want to keep. I would suggest you get a third variable for this grouping somehow, i.e., "Trials" or whatever.
I edited the response to reflect on the ordering, using `lag()` and `lead()`.

Comment: You are right, to be picky I can add a Time variable that gives order! sorry